# Updating UILabel in a block

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In iOS7 app I have the following code and the label is not being updated nor is the activity indicator hidden.  I am not very conversant in iOS threading but I assumed that AFNetworking block will not return to the main queue.  Either way if I remove the dispatch_async line I still have the same issues.  Can someone help me resolve this please

```
[myClient getPath:urlMethodWithParameters parameters:nil
          success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
              NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

              [self processFullDataString: responseString];
          }
          failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {


              dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                  [self hideActivityIndicator];

                  [self updateProgressLabelWithText:@"Unabke to downloading sync data ..."];

                  UIAlertViewAutoDismiss *alert = [[UIAlertViewAutoDismiss alloc] initWithTitle:@"Information" message: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Could not load data from the PromoPortal server - %@", [error localizedDescription]] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil,nil];
                  [alert show];
                  });
              }];
}
```

Comment: You added it in failure block, and didn't mention anything in success block.

Comment: I know.  I have the same problem in success block.  All the updates on the main thread from the processFullDataString in the success block also have the same issue.  Currently I am causing error so the code in failure block gets executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The execution context of a completion handler should always be documented. Historically, AFN dispatches on the main thread (which isn't the best way IMHO, though).

Here, you have *two* completion handlers: a *success* handler and a *failure* handler. You need to ensure that in each completion handler the UIKit elements are updated accordingly.

Comment: It maybe in the main thread and that the main thread is too busy running the long running task and unable to update the UI.  How would I fix this?  Create a new queue and run the AFN code in that and wrap any UI updates in dispatch_async?

Comment: Unlikely the main thread is that busy. You may set a breakpoint in the handler, and check if it get called once the request has been finished. You may also just halt the app in the debugger, check the thread view and examine whether and what the main thread is doing.

Comment: Note: if `[self processFullDataString: responseString];` is a synchronous long running task, and the handler executes on the main thread, you *hog on* the main tread, so that UIKit updates won't happen. You should dispatch this method onto a private queue. Note: AFN dispatches its completion handler on the main thread.

Comment: Handler called but no UI update.  The processFullDataString was a synchronous long running task and I have now wrapped it in a queue as follows

                      // Create a background thread to process the XML data
                      dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
                      dispatch_async(queue, ^{
                          [self processFullDataString: responseString];
                      });

UI update is showing but I am getting a crash looks like it is accessing managedObjectContext within this new queue

Comment: Does AFN dispatch to main queue in failure block too?

Comment: Should I open another question.  I can now update the UI from the long running thread but accessing MOC objects in there cause BAD ACCESS error sometimes, very randomly

Comment: Just read on another thread that new threads require new MOC but I am reusing the MOC created in the main thread ... investigating ...

Comment: AFN will dispatch handlers to the main thread. If you have a Core Data question you are better off asking this in a different question ;)

Comment: Thanks CouchDev. Haven't got enough rep to +1 you but I have accepted your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [self processFullDataString: responseString];
```

This is not called on the UI thread. Did you try wrapping it around with a main queue block too?

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
      [self processFullDataString: responseString];
};
```

Comment: how does this even remotely answer the users question?

Comment: @drUniversalis,

I don't want to run that long running code in the main queue!

Comment: Well he asked why nothing happens, my guess was its always successful an thus not calling "processFullDataString" on the main queue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the failure block:

```
- (void)performSelectorOnMainThread:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg waitUntilDone:(BOOL)wait
```

Comment: This didn't work. It actually crashed the app :-( I think the main thread is too busy. @couchDeveloper may be right about the AFN returning to the main queue